# Function to replace newlines with \n gets rid of lines of markdown that start with \n or -

Tags: javascript, markdown

I've got a javascript function that runs with node, designed to take markdown and minify it. However when I use ordered or unordered lists (with - or 1. ...), the lists are omitted entirely. The function that does this is this -

```
function convert (content) {
  return content
    .replace(/\t/g, '  ')
    .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
    .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
    .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
}
```

It's the `.replace(/\n/g, '\\n')` line which is causing the issue, but I have no idea why.

The text I was parsing was

```
A predictable pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) can lead to security issues where the number generated is being used as certain values security-critical, such as:  
- In a CSRF token 
- As a session token 
- Any secret value 
...
```

which was minified to

```
A predictable pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) can lead to security issues where the number generated is being used as certain values security-critical, such as\n ...
```

Comment: You should pots a sample of the text you are parsing

Comment: that's a good idea, I'll add it here, the text I was parsing was 

```A predictable pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) can lead to security issues where the number generated is being used as certain values security-critical, such as: 
- In a CSRF token
- As a session token
- Any secret value
...```

and it got minified to 

```A predictable pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) can lead to security issues where the number generated is being used as certain values security-critical, such as\n
...```

Comment: In general it is best to put all of that information in the question it self and not the comments =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `.replace(/\n/g, '\\\\n')`

Just like in the your existing line `.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')`, you need to add additional escape characters to have the output show the escaped new line character.

Comment: I have tried that, but the only difference was that the `\n` was replaced with `\\n`, the lists still disappeared for some reason

Answer (score 0):

So your code actually works just fine.

Try this for the file reader, does this fix the issue?

```
fs.readFile(filePath, 
        {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'},
        function(err, data) {
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        convert(data);
});
```

```js
function convert (content) {
  return content
    .replace(/\t/g, '  ')
    .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
    .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
    .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
}

console.log(convert(
`A predictable pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) can lead to security issues where the number generated is being used as certain values security-critical, such as:  
- In a CSRF token 
- As a session token 
- Any secret value 
...`
));
```

Comment: ```const fs = require('fs')

function convert (content) {
  return content
    .replace(/\t/g, '  ')
    .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
    .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
    .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
}


function run (filePath) {
  let content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')
  console.log(convert(content))
}

if (require.main === module) {
  run(process.argv[2])
}

module.exports = {
  'convert': convert,
  'run': run
}```
This is the rest of the code, it just takes a filepath and reads a file from there

Comment: Please add that to your original question =)

Comment: @dapawa Can you also put in your question what the value of the content form that printline you get from the file reader is?